# Convert SQL query into DAX query for PowerBI visual

Tags: powerbi

I have a table like below and trying to count the number of job_ids that are in "PAUSED" status in databricks and indicate it in PowerBI report.
If there is job id that has both of "PAUSED" and "UNPAUSED" status with the same timestamp, I should count that job_id as well as it's in the "PAUSED" status.

table1

| job_id | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | PAUSED | 2022-08-02T21:09:13 |
| A | UNPAUSED | 2022-08-02T21:09:13 |
| B | PAUSED | 2022-08-10T21:09:15 |
| B | PAUSED | 2022-07-20T21:09:13 |
| A | PAUSED | 2022-08-12T21:09:13 |
| C | PAUSED | 2022-08-01T21:07:19 |
| C | PAUSED | 2022-08-01T21:07:19 |
| C | UNPAUSED | 2022-08-03T21:07:19 |
| B | UNPAUSED | 2022-07-20T21:09:13 |
| A | UNPAUSED | 2022-08-04T21:09:13 |

and this is the sql query I wrote

```
SELECT count(job_id) FROM (SELECT distinct job_id,status,DENSE_RANK over() partition 
     by job_id order by timestamp desc AS rn FROM table1) t2 WHERE 
     t2.rn  = 1 and t2.status = "PAUSED"
```

What I want to do next is to display the number in PowerBI using the card visual.
To do that I think I need to convert the sql query above into DAX query to get the correct number..(not sure if there is better way to perform it, I'm new to PowerBI)
Anyone could help me with this query..?

Would appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power BI you would need the following measure:

```
Paused Jobs = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[job_id]),
    'Table'[status] = "PAUSED"
)
```

You can then put this measure onto a Card visual next to your data table

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but I need to distinct the job_id as well here, so the # of the paused jobs should be 3 here, is there anyway to do it?

Comment: then use the COUNTDISTINCT() function instead of count. Like this:Paused Jobs = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTDISTINCT('Table'[job_id]),
    'Table'[status] = "PAUSED"
)

Comment: It works thank you :) I also just wonder if I can order the job_id by timestamp descending and count the number of the paused jobs..? what I mean is that if there is a job_id with "UNPAUSED" status in later timestamp and "PAUSED" status in the earlier timestamp, then it's in "UNPAUSED"  status. So the job_id shouldn't be counted in the measure.. thats why I used the dense rank in my sql query. Can I do it in DAX query as well?

Comment: Yes, You can sort it according to the timestamp descending. In 2nd part of your question,My answer is yes:  you can also do it; but It requires a different DAX code approach; but not a difficult task. you need to group by job_id,and then check the max timestamp matching the group_id. If It corresponds to unpaused status, the do not count it in the actual countdistinct() measure function.

Comment: The problem here are the duplicate timestamps in the sample data which you most likely don't have in the real data.

Comment: If you don't have duplicate timestamps you can use the solution here: [Last status by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73461171/last-status-by-date)

Comment: I have duplicate timestamps in the table unfortunately.. :<

Comment: Hi @MMV Your SQL query counts the job id's which are in the "PAUSED" status. On the other hand, Your DAX code on the above comment use RANKX() to rank last_execution_time by distinct count. They are different entities. Also Your above sql code is incorrect if you are using MySQL

Comment: This is the correct Sql code in your post:SELECT count(job_id)
FROM (SELECT distinct job_id,status,DENSE_RANK() over(partition 
     by job_id order by timestamp desc) AS rn FROM table1) t2 WHERE 
     t2.rn  = 1 and t2.status = "PAUSED";

Comment: @MMV, Now Check My solution. I will show you how to obtain the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I hope This is what you want :

If we test the summary table:

```
Paused_Jobs =
VAR SummaryTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            SUMMARIZE ( table1, table1[job_id], table1[status] ),
            table1[status] = "PAUSED"
        ),
        "Latest", CALCULATE ( VALUES ( table1[timestamp] ), LASTDATE ( table1[timestamp] ) ),
        "TotalCount", CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( table1 ), LASTDATE ( table1[timestamp] ) )
    )
VAR Result =
    SUMX ( SummaryTable, [TotalCount] )
RETURN
    SummaryTable
```

And the resulting screenshot:

[image: Latest]

You can check the result with sql query :

[image: SQL Query Coloured]

If It is what you want, and want it as a measure:

```
Paused_Jobs =
VAR SummaryTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            SUMMARIZE ( table1, table1[job_id], table1[status] ),
            table1[status] = "PAUSED"
        ),
        "Latest", CALCULATE ( VALUES ( table1[timestamp] ), LASTDATE ( table1[timestamp] ) ),
        "TotalCount", CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( table1 ), LASTDATE ( table1[timestamp] ) )
    )
VAR Result =
    SUMX ( SummaryTable, [TotalCount] )
RETURN
    Result
```

[image: FG]

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer. but I don't really see any difference between the result of the first answer and this one.. I need to rank the job_id and status by timestamp and pick the most recent one because I need to check the latest status for each job id. Sometimes we pause the job and resume it in databricks for some reason, so if I only count the jobs with Paused status, I will count the old result as well..

Comment: Your goal is clear for me now. Just wait for my answer.

Comment: Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hello, Please check it. I updated my solution.

Comment: Hi @Ozan Sen! Your answer looks correct but it's throwing an error like this "Couldn't load the data for this visual.
MdxScript(Model) (12, 58) Calculation error in measure 'table1'[# of
paused jobs]: A date column containing duplicate dates was specified
in the call to function 'LASTDATE'. This is not supported." how can I resolve this error?

Comment: @MMV I tested and worked. I can't understand Why It gives such an error. Are you sure you copied the measure correctly ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247554/discussion-between-mmv-and-ozan-sen).