# Last status by date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table of task runs with timestamp and status:

| Timestamp | Task | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-19 12:34:11 | 1 | success |
| 2022-08-20 18:14:33 | 2 | failure |
| 2022-08-21 09:03:10 | 1 | failure |
| 2022-08-22 22:12:02 | 3 | failure |
| 2022-08-23 03:52:09 | 2 | success |
| 2022-08-24 15:38:42 | 3 | success |

I'm looking for the latest status by timestamp for each task plus the total number of tasks that are currently in "success" status.

The expected outcome is

| Task | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | failure |
| 2 | success |
| 3 | success |

so **2** tasks are currently in status "success".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The time intelligence function LASTDATE() returns a table (albeit with only one value) and can be directly used as a filter in CALCULATE():

```
Last Status = 
CALCULATE (
    VALUES ( Tasks[Status] ),
    LASTDATE ( Tasks[Timestamp] )
)
```

If this measure is filtered by Task (e.g. in a table) it returns the status from the last timestamp:

[image]

2. Counting the successful tasks is a bit trickier, since the above measure can't be filtered directly, but an intermediate table is needed:

```
Count Success = 
VAR tbl =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        VALUES ( Tasks[Task] ),
        "Status", [Last Status]
    )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            tbl,
            [Status] = "success"
        )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Peter, LastDATE is not  a modifier. Modifier is a different concept in DAX world. ALL, KEEPFILTERS, USERELATIONSHIP, CROSSFILTER, ALLEXCEPT are called modifiers. You need to ask yourself this question: Where should I use LASTDATE() and Where should I use MAX() function ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's first create the table:

[image: FDFG]

Now This is the code:

```
Result =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    VALUES ( YourTbl[Task] ),
    "MaxDate", CALCULATE ( VALUES ( YourTbl[Status] ), LASTDATE ( YourTbl[Timestamp] ) ),
    "SuccessCount", CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( YourTbl ), YourTbl[Status] = "success" )
)
```

The result It produces :

[image: GGG]

Comment: Thx, I wasn't aware of LASTDATE(), very convenient. How about the count of "success"?